# How to serialize struct with multiple fields protected by tokio's RwLock?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, serde

I use [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) to listen on UDP socket where I send/receive [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) encoded structs and serialize/deserialize them with [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde).

How should I approach the serialization of `Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<T>>` fields? Serde supports standard library `RwLock` but I need an async lock.

Data is being changed and transferred over the network fairly often (by design), so it's probably not a good idea to wait for multiple read locks every time I need to send something.

And considering that serde is synchronous, I'd have to spawn blocking tokio tasks in place for every `RwLock` field. (And every field has `RwLock` fields of their own). So this will get really slow.

Here's an example struct:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tokio::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Player {
    // In order to serialize Player I'd have to one by one acquire lock for `meta` and then `stats`, and then some other potential fields.
    pub id: u64,
    pub meta: Arc<RwLock<Metadata>>,
    pub stats: Arc<RwLock<Metadata>>,  
    pub someOtherField1: Arc<RwLock<...>>,
    pub someOtherField2: Arc<RwLock<...>>,
    pub someOtherField3: Arc<RwLock<...>>,
}
```

What is the Rust way of dealing with this?

Comment: What if someone modifies the player object while you're serializing it? Do you send an inconsistent state which is half the old state half the new state?

Comment: Are the arcs shared (i.e. is their reference count greather than 1) at the moment when you serialize players?

Comment: @orlp i haven't thought about that much, though i think in some cases this wouldn't be a problem, but in some cases, it would.

Comment: @user4815162342 they could be shared i guess

Comment: Once again, it is very fast-paced data (think multiplayer games and such). Things are changing very frequently and sometimes it doesn't matter if they get out of sync a little.

Comment: If the system is running (i.e. other threads can acquire the lock for writing and modify the data) during serialization, I really don't see a way, Rust or otherwise, to avoid acquiring the locks when serializing. If changing the design is not the option, I'd approach it by creating a `PlayerSnapshot` struct that holds data without the arcs/rwlocks (and is therefore trivially serializable), and create a `async fn to_snapshot(&self) -> PlayerSnapshot` which I'd call prior to deserialization. There would also be a `async fn from_snapshot(snapshot: PlayerSnapshot) -> Player` on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Data is being changed and transferred over the network fairly often (by design), so it's probably not a good idea to wait for multiple read locks every time i need to send something.

Forget performance - this won't be your bottleneck in any sort of game networking (which does appear what you're trying to do).

The only **correct** way is to *first* acquire a read lock on each field before serializing the data, and then serialize them all. If you don't do this you end up with inconsistent states *that never logically existed*. A player could be alive yet have 0 hitpoints, or be disconnected yet in the game.

This can lead to deadlocks! This is the difficulty you chose when you started sharing data. There is a very good rule of thumb that can prevent deadlocks if you stick to it religiously, which you have to do throughout your code: **any routine that acquires multiple locks must acquire them in the same order.** If a new lock is needed but we already have other locks that come later in the order, we must first release all locks before acquiring them all again, in the correct order.

The easiest way to stick to the above is by having only a single lock for a player.